# Will I be able to get the free Pokemon game if I link that same 3DS that I've unlinked from Club Nintendo a while back?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, club-nintendo

My 3DS used to be linked to Club Nintendo but I unlinked it a while back. Will I be able to get the free Pokemon game if I link that same 3DS again? Or will it recognize it still? I'm not sure how Club Nintendo works on relinking. I was planning on getting a 3DS XL but decided against it. This free game might push me back into buying that XL especially since I really want to get Animal Crossing which is one of the games required for the free Pokemon one. However, if somehow I can pull getting the free game on the 3DS I already have then I can wait for the XL. Thanks.

Here's info on the promotion: http://club2.nintendo.com/3ds-pokemon-promo/
You get a free Pokemon game (Either X or Y) if you register a specific game from that list and a 3DS within the month of March

Answer (score 2):

The promotion is specifically about **purchasing and registering** a new 2/3DS system and one of the games. From http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3743/p/52:

> Buy and register a Nintendo 2DS™, Nintendo 3DS™, or Nintendo 3DS XL
>   system and any one of six qualifying games (below) between 3/1/14
>   (12:01 a.m. PT) and 3/31/14 (11:59 p.m. PT) and you'll receive a free
>   download code for the digital version of Pokémon™ X or Pokémon Y.

You won't be able to re-register a previously linked 3DS.

Answer (score -1):

You can get a linked game it doesn`t  matter what kind of game you get you can get the same game trust me i did it before with mario this will work.